# 'deleted: no' in combination with 'answers:0' kills all search results (hides the bodies at least)

Tags: support, search-box

I was playing around with the Stack Overflow search and the search parameters listed under *Advanced Search Tips*.

Everything worked fine until the delete: no was added.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+answers%3A0+deleted%3Ano

The combination of `answers:1 deleted: no` works fine again.

This feels like a bug to me, because if I remove the `deleted: no` I see a lot of not deleted questions.

It might be cause all the results are limited to my own questions, because I see a comment with my user id above it. But if that is the case I would recommend putting the `deleted: no` in a separate category under the *Advanced Search Tips*, because it's definitely a separate behaviour to the other toggles you can set and doesn't do what you expect really.

A category with: Limiting to your contributions, or something similar in meaning that might be a little bit less verbose would make it more clear that it limits the search results to the contributions made by the searcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). This is linked directly in advanced search tips

The `deleted` parameter looks for *your* deleted posts.

> deleted:0 searches only not-deleted posts that you've authored (effectively the same as user:me)

**deleted:no** seems to work the same way.

So you are not searching for what you intend to.

**Update**:

Comparing the advanced search tips and [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching),

The status parameters section (closed, duplicate, migrated, wiki) all coincide with the boolean operators while `deleted` is a different parameter. It doesnt seem to belong there

Comment: Yea, I gather that, but hence my argument from putting it under a separate category under the advanced search tips, to set it apart from the rest, because it adds an unexpected limiter you're not aware of when just looking at the list.

Comment: hmm `Status- deleted:no` might make it odd . There is also the banner `Note: only content you own is returned when searching for deleted content` in the search results

Comment: yea, but I was searching for "not deleted content". I learned about this outlier flag now for the search box, I just find that the advanced search tips still could put it in a seperate category, because it includes a non intuitive guessable flag. You only see it  after studying everything there, and fighting the brain reflex, because that sentence does not equal my intention so my brain automatically discards it as relevant. now I know it's relevant, but it's only after a long process, relatively speaking.